# ejabberd embeded in Elixir - mix release failed

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I am trying to include ejabberd in elixir app, as described at https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/extending-ejabberd/elixir/. Everything works, however when I want to create release package from app using `mix release`, I got error:

```
** (Mix) :p1_utils is listed both as a regular application and as an included application
```

Any idea how to solve this? My exs is very simple, just ejabberd with no other deps.

```
defmodule Ejapp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :ejapp,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.9",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:ejabberd, "~> 19.2"}
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `def application, do: []` looks a bit weird; even if compiled, your release will not be robust because it has no application declared.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you fix it eventually?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your application or one of your dependencies includes `p1_utils` as an optional dependency (`:included_applications`) and another dependency does include it as a real dependency (which is the same as explicit including it into the list of `:applications` in `mix` project file.)

Since *your* application does not include it, I would go through all the dependencies of `:ejabberd` and find a culprit. Usually, the issue might be solved by patching the dependency inside the dependency tree before doing `mix release`.

I would not consider this being an issue with `mix release` because even despite `:applications` is more strict, the dependency might use `:included_applications` to postpone the custom initialization  and there might be a conflict with it being already started from another dependency.